# Prevent SQL Injections

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sql-injection

I am trying to prevent sql injection: like 1=1 , etc. First time doing this and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right?

Here is the code: The connection string is there I just removed it for the purpose of this question.

```
   public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String login = txtUser.Text;
        String pass = txtPass.Text;

            string connString = "";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Users,Pass from logintable where Users='" + txtUser.Text + "' and Pass='" + txtPass.Text + "'", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Users", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = login;


            SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                new Login().Show();
            }
            else
            {
                 lblFail.Text="Invalid username or password";
           }





        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Side-note: storing passwords in plaintext is *bad*. You should hash them properly, using a strong KDF. Check out [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for details on what's necessary, and [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt/17435#17435) for an in-depth look at *why* we need to use KDFs instead of plain hashes.

Answer (score 2):

You are directly passing values to your query. it causes the Sql Injection. So you need to use Sql Parameters to avoid it. here is an idea for you

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Users,Pass from logintable where Users=@user and Pass=@password", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note your use of string concatenation in:

```
"Select Users,Pass from logintable where Users='" + txtUser.Text + "' and Pass='" + txtPass.Text + "'"
```

That's what makes your code vulnerable to injection.  You need parameter placeholders:

```
"Select Users, Pass from logintable where Users=@Users and Pass=@Pass", conn);
```

You can find a complete example of how to properly use parameters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is completely wrong. You can still be injected via `txtUser.Text` and `txtPass.Text`, because you're using string concatenation.

You need to use parameters for those two values in the query, then bind the two `.Text` properties onto the query before execution.

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Users,Pass from logintable where Users=@username and Pass=@password", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUser.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPass.Text);
```

Of course, you should never store passwords directly in plaintext like this. You should look into [proper password storage practice!](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Command` object but you are not parameterizing the value which defeats its purpose, you can use `AddWithValue()` method on the command object to define its parameters,

```
string query = "Select Users,Pass from logintable where Users=@user and Pass=@pass";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPass.Text);
```

Additionally, you can use `ExecuteScalar()` from the `Command` object rather than using `DataReader` object to fetch single value on the result.

Try this code snippet:

```
string connStr = "connection string here";
string sqlStatement = @"SELECT COUNT(*) TotalCount
                        FROM logintable 
                        WHERE Users=@user and Pass=@pass";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUser.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPass.Text);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int _result = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
            if (_result > 0)
            {
                new Login().Show();
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for propr object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle objects

Answer (score 0):

You should never construct SQL statements using string concatenation, use parametrized queries always. Please try this code :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Users, Pass from logintable where Users= @Users  AND Pass=@Pass", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Users", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
cmd.Parameters["@Users"].Value = login;
cmd.Parameters["@Pass"].Value = pass;

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read()) 
{
   new Login().show();
}
else
{
   lblFail.Text = "Invalid username and password";
}
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();

conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Hope this helps. You should use the above code in a try-catch block with Close/Dispose calls in the finally block.